# Start a systemd service after network but before other services

Tags: linux, systemd-unit

I want my service to start after network service but before all other services (eg. tomcat or mysql).

I know about "Before=mysqld.service" option but I do not know all the names of the services on different machines. So I want some global option where I do not need to know the name of each service.

Comment: There's no such thing as "before all other services" because what if two services did that?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#network.target

You can't force systemd to start your service before all the others that use the same target without knowing who they are.\

`systemd` is not a fortune teller that you can ask questions you don't know 
You need to give it exact orders if you want it to act exactly to your needs...

Maybe use a combination of the first link with: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#network-online.target